# How to convert decimal number to string from R.class

Tags: java, android

I decompiled some android mobile application and I noticed to some class named `R.class` and inside it I saw lots of integer numbers assigned to variables:

```
public static final int _TS_faceauth_icon_label = 2131820616;
public static final int _TS_faceauth_message_abort = 2131820617;
public static final int _TS_faceauth_message_auth = 2131820618;
public static final int _TS_faceauth_message_enroll_1 = 2131820619;
public static final int _TS_faceauth_message_enroll_2 = 2131820620;
public static final int _TS_faceauth_message_enroll_3 = 2131820621;
public static final int _TS_faceauth_message_enroll_4 = 2131820622;
public static final int _TS_faceauth_message_enroll_5 = 2131820623;
```

I used some mobile app analyzer such [MobSF](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) to analyze it and found that:

```
_TS_faceauth_icon_label="Face"
```

which inside the code is:

```
public static final int _TS_faceauth_icon_label = 2131820616;
```

What these numbers mean?
Are they pointer to other strings?
How can I convert them manually ?

Comment: They are unique value for each id in XML.

Comment: How can I convert them manually ? what XML ? I have the AndroidManifests XML, do you mean that ?

Comment: android layouts files are called XML file.

Comment: No it's not possible to convert them into real value

Comment: looks like you are missing Android basics about how the resources work.